# Decremento em um campo da tabela asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Estou desenvolvendo gerenciador de cursos em **asp.net MVC**, e na tabela de cursos tem um campo **qtd_vagas**. Gostaria de saber como eu faço pra fazer um **count--** (**ou alguma outra forma de Decrementar**) esse campo. Por exemplo: Na lista de cursos vai aparecer os cursos e a quantidade de vagas e um botão inscrever. O aluno ao clicar em inscrever, o campo **qtd_vagas** vai diminuindo a quantidade de vagas existentes na tabela e na tela. Cursos com 50 vagas, se uma inscrição for efetuada vai diminuindo 49, 48, 47... Como eu faço para o campo ir atualizando automaticamente tanto tabela como na tela do usuário!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estou supondo que você está usando Entity Framework para abstrair o banco de dados. Um exemplo de `Action` no *Controller* seria algo assim:

```
public ActionResult Inscrever(int id) // Este id é o id do curso
{
    // Aqui penso que ocorreria uma seleção do aluno logado.
    // Depois uma associação do aluno ao curso.
    // Suponho que o curso seria colocado em uma variável "curso".
    curso.QuantidadeVagas--;
    context.Entry(curso).State = EntityState.Modified;
    context.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("AlgumaAction", "AlgumController");
}
```

Só que como são várias operações de banco que você faz aqui (selecionar aluno, selecionar curso, criar associação, modificar curso), [recomendo você usar escopo transacional](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn456843.aspx#transactionScope). Aí ficaria assim:

```
public ActionResult Inscrever(int id) 
{
    using (var scope = new TransactionScope()) 
    {
        // Aqui penso que ocorreria uma seleção do aluno logado.
        // Depois uma associação do aluno ao curso.
        // Suponho que o curso seria colocado em uma variável "curso".
        curso.QuantidadeVagas--;
        context.Entry(curso).State = EntityState.Modified;
        context.SaveChanges();

        scope.Complete(); 
    }

    return RedirectToAction("AlgumaAction", "AlgumController");
}
```

Para exibição na tela, é trivial: a atualização do valor do curso irá refletir automaticamente na apresentação:

```
@model Curso

<h1>Quantidade de Vagas: @Model.QuantidadeVagas</h1>
```

---

Um exemplo de Ajax seria um botão assim:

```
<button id="decremento" name="1">Decrementar</button>
```

Adicione o jQuery às suas *Views* ([procure usar *Bundling*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A2999+bundle)) e escreva algo assim:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#decremento").click(function() {
            $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: '/MeuController/Inscrever/' + $(this).attr("name")
            });
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

Comment: Estou utilizando o **Entity Framework** @Cigano. Sou aprendiz ainda do asp.net mvc. Gostaria de saber como eu faço para associar esse decremento ao clique do botão.

Comment: Aí você teria que usar Ajax pra chamar a `Action`. O código da solução não muda muito. Normalmente jQuery resolve isto bem.

Comment: você tem algum exemplo de Ajax?

Comment: @Novato Sim, veja a edição que fiz agora.

Comment: Não sei o que estou fazendo de errado @Cigano, mas na ação do meu botão não tá acontecendo nada. Adicionei o JQuery na minha View '<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>' e fiz igual tá no exemplo. '<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#inscricao").click(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: 'Curso/Inscrever' + $(this).attr("name")
                });
            });

        });
    </script>'

Comment: @Novato Se você colocar um breakpoint na `Action` do `Controller`, a execução para nele?

Comment: Coloquei o breakpoint, e não para lá. Não faz nada. @Cigano

Comment: Primeiro você tem que conseguir chamar a `Action`. Se você não marcou a `Action` com `[HttpPost]`, não vai funcionar.

Comment: Olha minha Action @Cigano                                                    `[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Inscrever(int id)
        {
            var curso = new Curso();
            curso.Qtd_Vagas--;
            db.Entry(curso).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();

            return PartialView("PartialCursoIndex", db.Cursos);
        }`

Comment: Help me @Cigano, dá uma força aqui!? Por gentileza.

Comment: @Novato Faça outra pergunta, por favor. Não coloque código nos comentários. Seja mais objetivo no seu erro ou problema. Explique como está seu código e o que foi feito para que o problema seja reproduzido.